# RegExp for <a ...> but not for <a ... target="something" ...>

Tags: c#, regex

Please help to rewrite all links without "target" attribute.

For example, the text is:

```
<a href="google.com" onclick="alert('Hello!!')">My Link 1</a>
<a href="my.com" class="some-class">My Link 2</a>
<a href="dot.net" target="_parent" class="some-class">My Link 3</a>
<a href="find.me" class="some-class">My Link 4</a>
```

The text is needed to got:

```
<a href="google.com" onclick="alert('Hello!!')" target="_blank">My Link 1</a>
<a href="my.com" class="some-class" target="_blank">My Link 2</a>
<a href="dot.net" target="_parent" class="some-class">My Link 3</a>
<a href="find.me" class="some-class" target="_blank">My Link 4</a>
```

3rd link is untouched, other links have attribute "target" now.

Please help to compose Regular Expression correct. I tried this:

```
Regex.Replace(text, "<(a)([^>]+)(((?! target=).)*$)([^>]+)>", "<$1 target=\"_parent\" $2 $3>");
```

but it's not working.

"Html Agility Pack" is undesirable.

Comment: Don't [parse html with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1895201)

Comment: It's impossible to understand what author wanted to tell there. I still want to parse string with Regex.

Comment: Hmm, do you want some other solution that can make it without Regex?

Comment: @user1820034 Are you familiar with satire? What's wrong with HTML agility pack? It was built for these sort of tasks. Why are you pre-emptively rejecting the solution to your problem?

Comment: It should be small and simple solution. It's not desirable to install any packages or big classes.

Comment: You should use DOM or SAX parser for this.

Comment: I don't like HTML agility pack either, but I DON't recommend regex on parsing html. I have an app that parses HTML using SGMLReader and converting HTML to XML and there I would use XMLTextReader to parse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work as desired:

```
Regex.Replace(text, "<a(((?!target=).)*)\">", "<a$1\" target=\"_parent\">")
```

A small amount of assumption is required that every opening anchor tag you close must have the `"` character just before closing the opening tag with the `>` character.

i.e.
<a......`">`My link</a>

Comment: You can drop the small assumption by replacing the match for any character `.` by the match for any character except a closing bracket `>`, like so: `[^>]`. The full regex becomes: `<a(((?!target=)[^>])*)>`

Answer (score 1):

Solution for you:

```
Regex _r = new Regex("<a (.+?)>");
foreach (Match m in _r.Matches(text))
{
    string Link = m.Groups[0].Value;
    if (!Link.Contains("target"))
        text = text.Replace(Link, string.Format("{0} target=\"_parent\">", Link.Substring(0, Link.Length - 1)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried `Regex.Replace(text, "<(a)([^>]+)>", "<$1 target=\"_parent\" $2>")` already, but it also grabs all links with "target" attribute. I want to exclude them.

Comment: There are a lot of links with "target" and without "target" attributes in text. So `if(!text.Contains(...))` does not work.

Comment: Thank you for help. That's good, but I don't want to remove "target='something'". In your example, if "target='something'" exists, it's replaced with "target='_parent'", but it should be "target='something'".

Answer (score 0):

May be something easier like this ? :

```
if (false == text.Contains("target="))
{
   Regex.Replace(text, "<(a)([^>]+)(((?! target=).)*$)([^>]+)>", "<$1 target=\"_parent\" $2 $3>");
}
```

Comment: It does not work because variable "text" contains a lot of html tags with or without "target" attribute.